# ASP.NET MVC conditional routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my MVC Application I have my routes defined as follows:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Category_default",
            "{lang}/Category/{categoryid}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { lang = "en", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, categoryid = -1 }
        ).DataTokens.Add("area", "Category");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "home", action = "index", lang = "en", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

The application works fine. However, the system administrator just brought to my knowledge that those users who don't have access to the category (in other words, they are logically not associated with it) can also see the data just by switching the categoryid parameter, which is no surprise since I haven't put any check there.

What's the efficient way of checking if the user has privileges over this category or not. In the system I have a User object with User.AllowedCategories List which contains integer values of all the ids the user has access to.

The category area has about 20 controllers (therefore 20 views). Should I put a logic to check on every view? Or I can do it with minimum coding / or can I put this logic globally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that in 3 ways,

**Method 1: Global Filters**

In FilterConfig.cs:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
   filters.Add(new ValidateUserFilter());
}
```

In ValidateUserFilter.cs

```
public class ValidateUserFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {

    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        //Controllers to avoid validation
        if ((new[] { "<<CONTROLLER1>>", "<<CONTROLLER2>>" }).Any(x => x == filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName))
        {
            return;
        }

        if (!User.AllowedCategories.Any(x => x == FilterContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"]))
        {
            //Redirect user to unauthorized page.
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary { { "Controller", "<<CONTROLLER_NAME>>" }, { "Action", "<<ACTION_NAME>>" } });
        }
    }
}
```

**Method 2: FilterAttribute**

```
public class ValidateControllerAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!User.AllowedCategories.Any(x => x == filterContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"]))
        {
            //Redirect user to unauthorized page.
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary { { "Controller", "<<CONTROLLER_NAME>>" }, { "Action", "<<ACTION_NAME>>" } });

            //OR, You can redirect to 403 response
            //throw new HttpException((int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "You do not have permission to view this page");
        }
    }
}
```

> You have to add this attribute in every controller which you want to
>   validate

Ex:

```
[ValidateController]
public class MyControllerController : Controller
```

**Method 3: ActionMethodSelectorAttribute**

```
public class ValidateActionAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        if (!User.AllowedCategories.Any(x => x == controllerContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"]))
        {
            //Redirect user to unauthorized page.
            controllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
            controllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("~/<<CONTROLLER_NAME>>/<<ACTION_NAME>>");
            return false;

            //OR, You can redirect to 403 response
            //throw new HttpException((int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "You do not have permission to view this page");

            /*OR,
            controllerContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 403;
            return true;*/
        }
    }
}
```

> You have to add this attribute in every action which you want to
>   validate

Ex:

```
[ValidateAction]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Hi @Palani Kumar can you please tell what to write in the onActionExecuting?

Comment: Thanks for the update @Palani Kumar, I just have one question now. As you can see I have two areas. I want this filter to be only applicable in the "Category" area. How can I achieve that?

Comment: @progrAmmar, Better you can use the Method 2: FilterAttribute. You have to add the attribute [ValidateController] in each controller in "Category" area.

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, essentially the problem is that, unauthorized user is able to access parts of application, which it should not.

You can use `Authorize` attribute on your action methods, OR on the Controller class, depending on what areas you want to have authorization. If your design allows, you can also consider creating a `base controller` and apply Authorize attribute on that, if you do not want repetitions.

Now specify the valid users for these controllers, using `Roles` OR `Users` parameters

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Valid Roles", Users = "Valid Users")]
```

If the default Authorize attribute doesn't suffice your needs you can always create your own custom attribute for authorization.

Comment: I think requirement is not about role based authorization. A level below the authorization. i.e. category level access control